# How to redirect only matching mailboxes to a smart host

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, smarthost

I have o365/Exchange configured as an internal relay, so it sends incoming mail for which there is no mailbox onwards to a smart host. The smart host only handles email for addresses prefixed with "otm-".

However the problem is that NDRs aren't generated in this configuration.

I have tried to solve this by making o365/Exchange authoritative for the domain and configuring a rule to redirect only incoming email with the "otm-" prefix in the recipient address to the smart host but I haven't been able to get this right — now everything except the main o365/Exchange mailboxes gets an NDR.

I think I have the rule correct but I think emails are being rejected before the rule is processed.

How should I go about configuring this?

Comment: You can have a read at this similar case, https://serverfault.com/questions/802555/relay-specific-exchange-mailbox-to-defined-smtp-host Within your organization configuration, setup a send connector for a specific domain and configure it to route mail to the ticketing system's SMTP server as the smart host. You can also read this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail

Comment: Thanks but that answer covers the case of forwarding a know address by adding a contact, but not unknown addresses (prefixed with "otm-") which is what I need.  The MS doc doesn't address this case, just general setup of connectors and rules.

Comment: Any updates with the issue?

Comment: I'm planning to make the domain non-authoritive and then generate NDRs from rules. If this works out I'll self-answer at some point, though it's a messy solution.

Comment: Have you made it now? Thanks for sharing.